# View frame set by UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate undone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a custom `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` that animates in a `UIViewController` with a custom animation and custom view frame. The effect of this presentation is to have a view controller like so:

[image]

Everything works well, and is done primarily using the method defined by `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`:

`- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext`

The problem that occurs is when another view controller is presented **on top** of this new view controller--with or without a custom `transitioningDelegate`. A simple `[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];` followed by a dismissal of that view controller will cause the originally presented view controller to lose the frame previously set for it. It will now resize to the bounds of the screen, like so:

[image]

Unfortunately, I am not seeing any events that I can intercept to prevent the frame from being undone. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Do you have constraints assigned?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Aside from UIViewAutoresizing masks, no. Everything is done pragmatically by setting the UIView frames.